# AngularJS ng-repeat not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJs and still trying to figure out how the basics work... I'm using the Soundcloud API to pull a list of followers for a given user. So far in my `$scope.init` function I am able to connect to Soundcloud, authenticate a user and return a json list of the user's followers. I then push each follower into an array called `$scope.results` and verify that the array is full by outputting it in the console. However when I try to output each follower as a list item in the array using `ng-repeat`  in my `main.html` view and I get nothing..... here's my code:

**main.js**

```
 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.apiKey = "##########################";
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.init = function(){
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: $scope.apiKey,
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:9000/callback.html"
    });
    // initiate auth popup
    SC.connect(function() {
        SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
        alert('Hello, ' + me.username); 
    });

    SC.get('/me/followers', function(followers) {
        //console.log(followers);
        //angular.forEach(followers, function(value, index){
            angular.forEach(followers, function(follower, index){
                $scope.results.push(follower);
            });
            console.log($scope.results);
    });
});
```

**main.html** // which is a view

```
`<div ng-init="init()">`
`<li ng-repeat="follower in results">`
`<div class="row-fluid">`
    `<div class="span3">`
       `<div class="span6">`
        <h3>{{follower.username}}</h3>
        <p>{{follower.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="soundSelectApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="container" ng-view></div>

<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
<script>
  var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
  (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing a call to $apply() because you are doing work outside of the angular world so try to add one line below push command and it should work

```
 angular.forEach(followers, function(follower, index){
                $scope.results.push(follower);
            });

$scope.$apply()
```